# Get Alfresco extension properties with OpenCMIS

Tags: alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm writing an [OpenCMIS](http://www.opencmis.org) based application, which extracts some data from Alfresco 3.3.

It works fine with *standard* CMIS properties such as `cmis:name` or `cmis:contentStreamMimeType`; however, I can't access Alfresco especific properties, which are present on the CMIS AtomPub feed as "Alfresco extensions":

```
<cmisra:object>
  <cmis:properties>
    <cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name" displayName="Name" queryName="cmis:name">
      <cmis:value>test document</cmis:value>
    </cmis:propertyString>
    <cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamMimeType" displayName="Content Stream MIME Type" queryName="cmis:contentStreamMimeType">
      <cmis:value>text/html</cmis:value>
    </cmis:propertyString>
    ...
    <alf:aspects>
      ...
      <alf:properties>
        <cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cm:description" displayName="Description" queryName="cm:description">
          <cmis:value>This is just a test document</cmis:value>
        </cmis:propertyString>
      </alf:properties>
    </alf:aspects>
  </cmis:properties>
</cmisra:object>
```

Is there any way in which I can get the value of `cm:descripcion`, with OpenCMIS?

My guess is that I need to use the `DocumentType` interface instead of `Document`, and then call its `getExtensions()` method. But I don't know how to get an instance of DocumentType.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards

---

**Edit:** altough Florian's answer already worked out for me, I've just realized that I can get these properties' values with CMIS SQL, too:

```
select d.*, t.*, a.*
from   cmis:document d
join   cm:titled t on d.cmis:objectid = t.cmis:objectid
join   cm:author a on d.cmis:objectid = a.cmis:objectid
where  t.cm:description like ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the OpenCMIS high-level API cannot access all extensions yet. It's on our to-do list. For now, you have to use the low-level API.
Something like this should work:

```
ObjectData doc = session.getBinding().getObjectService().getObject(...);
org.w3c.dom.Node domNode = (org.w3c.dom.Node) doc.getProperties().getExtensions().get(0); // <alf:aspects>
domNode.getFirstChild() ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Florian. Yes, it works. Thats almost what I did in my last attempt yesterday: session.getBinding().getObjectService().getProperties().getExtensions()... I was just trying the response (List<Object>) as Strings instead of as Nodes.

----- Glad to know that the high-level API may probably access extensions in a future release.

----- Thanks again and regards